# Any plugin of jQueryUI like jQuery EasyUI?

Tags: jquery

i've found this 3rd party plugin of jQueryUI

[jQuery EasyUI](http://jquery-easyui.wikidot.com/)

But i want to know is it another recommend?

Comment: Please elaborate. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: a collection of user-interface plugin based on jQuery.
For example, ExtJS have a set of ui framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the question, since you don't mention it at all and the plugin you link it actually a jQuery plugin (directly, not jQuery UI), make sure you haven't overlooked [jQuery UI itself](http://jqueryui.com/).  This is the official UI library for jQuery, [you can find demos here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

Another popular one is [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html), you can find demos on the same page, it's a bit more compact library that's less extensible, but if it suits your purposes, it is a lot lighter.

Comment: thanks you, yes, my question is bit confused :( i am sorry for my english. But you are good, jQuery Tools is what i looking for.thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion **Dojo toolkit** provides a lot of features ( [dojotoolkit.org](http://dojotoolkit.org/))

Answer (score 0):

No Source code available with this 'GPL' project making it unusable for commercial development. My advice is to avoid and opt for amore mainstream solution such as JQuery Tools.